# Web site statistics

Tags: web-analytics

I am looking for API which will return web site price, and statistics.

I found [Alexa services](http://aws.amazon.com/awis/#pricing) so far. It's great, but I did not found the web site price.

I found other site http://www.evaluateanywebsite.com/. That evaluate the site.

I am looking for API that will return :

1. Web-site traffic
2. Audience
3. Visits
4. Estimate evaluation

Please advise if you know similar API ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what you are trying to say with "web site price" but you may take a look at [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/)